# OOTB Workflow Completing Successfully Only If Triggered Inside the APP Server

Tags: workflow, 2016

I have a list with an Out-Of-The-Box (OOTB) workflow. It's a SharePoint 2010 workflow on the SP2016 platform.

If I am inside the server, I load the site, and I create a list item, the workflow successfully starts and completes.

If I am using a normal user machine or the Web Front End (WFE) server, I load the site, and I create a list item, the workflow fails to start.

Inside the server, the antivirus does not have blocking rules for emails.

I cannot find anything useful in the SharePoint logs. We're currently requesting for Event Viewer and IIS logs.

Note that subscribing to SharePoint alerts are working whether the SharePoint alert was triggered from inside or outside of the server (Example: I subscribed to all events on a list. Whether I create a list item from inside or outside of the server, I still get a SharePoint alert).

Any ideas on what to look for or how to further troubleshoot?

Advanced thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After my colleague checked again the SharePoint logs, the issue was really email related (filter by Category = "E-Mail").
[image]

The issue was fixed when my colleague set the outgoing email settings to the host name of the application server that hosts the SMTP service. Then in the virtual SMTP server's settings > **Advanced Delivery** > **Smart host**, he set it to the SMTP relay server name.
[image]